# Add navigation buttons to unified titlebar/toolbar

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsbutton, nstoolbar

Is there a way to get the the default `NSButton`s used throughout OS X for navigating through a window's contents? The buttons I'm speaking of are shown in Finder, System Preferences, Safari, Mac App Store, Game Center, etc.

[image]

While I could recreate them using my own `NSButton` and custom images for the chevrons, I would like to use these buttons if they're provided to ensure they're the exact same style, and they will update when this style undoubtedly changes appearance in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSSegmentedControl + NSImageNameGoLeftTemplate + NSImageNameGoRightTemplate 
(some (most?) of this can be specified via the nib)

```
[self.segmentedControl setSegmentCount:2];
self.segmentedControl.segmentStyle = NSSegmentStyleSeparated;
[[self.segmentedControl cell] setTrackingMode:NSSegmentSwitchTrackingMomentary];

[self.segmentedControl setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:NSImageNameGoLeftTemplate] forSegment:0];
[self.segmentedControl setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:NSImageNameGoRightTemplate] forSegment:1];

[[self.segmentedControl cell] setTag:0 forSegment:0];
[[self.segmentedControl cell] setTag:1 forSegment:1];

[self.segmentedControl setWidth:23.0 forSegment:0];
[self.segmentedControl setWidth:23.0 forSegment:1];

[self.segmentedControl setEnabled:YES forSegment:0];
[self.segmentedControl setEnabled:YES forSegment:1];

[self.segmentedControl sizeToFit];
```

The NSImages are documented here:
[System-Provided Images for Use in Controls](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/OSXHIGuidelines/SystemProvided.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000957-CH92-SW3)